# Loop Through An Array In PHP with 2 or more properties

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array with two properties and loop through it.
But I don't know how to do it.

In this example a have one property:

```
$foodArray = ["apple", "banana"];

foreach ($foodArray as $food)  {
    echo $food ."<br />";
}
```

Now I want to add in the array - green to apple and yellow to banana and loop the same way. How to do it in the best way?

Comment: So you're wanting to loop around `['green' => 'apple', 'yellow' => 'banana']`?

Comment: @Jonnix What if you have lime and apple? Both are green.

Comment: Define *"two properties"* please. Can you show us an example array?

Comment: @Qirel Dunno, thus I'm asking what $foodArray looks like for OPs new scenario.

Comment: I do wonder sometimes what some people use as their conditions for giving an upvote. At best the question seems unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add multiple properties by adding multiple elements within a sub-array

```
$foodArray = [['name' => 'Apple', 'color' => 'Yellow'], 
              ['name' => 'Banana', 'color' => 'yellow']];

foreach($foodArray as $fruit) {
    echo $fruit['name']." - ".$fruit['color']." <br />";
}
```

Or if you just need these two properties, you can use the key as the name, and the value as the color.

```
$foodArray = ['Apple' => 'green', 'Banana' => 'yellow'];
foreach($foodArray as $fruit => $color) {
    echo $fruit." - ".$color ." <br />";
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/jGePl

Comment: Or OP could be after `['green' => ['apple', 'lime'], 'yellow' => ['banana']]`, who knows.

Comment: Indeed, it should, @Sam. Thanks for pointing it out. I see I wasn't the only one who did that.. Makes you think ;-)

Comment: @Qirel yeah, think I had the same thought ;-P

Answer (score 2):

For looping over multiple properties, you need to use multi-dimensional arrays.

Basic concept is that an array should contain arrays.

Now these arrays can have multiple properties.

You need to take key value pairs.

So, your array would be:

```
$foodArray = ['green' => 'apple', 'yellow' => 'banana'];
foreach ($foodArray as $foodColor => $food)  {
 echo $foodColor . ' = ' $food ."<br />";
}
```

Or else, you can define multi-dimensional array and loop over it:

```
$foodArray = [];
$foodArray['apple']['name'] = ['apple'];
$foodArray['apple']['color'] = ['green'];

$foodArray['banana']['name'] = ['banana'];
$foodArray['banana']['color'] = ['yellow'];
```

And loop over it.

```
foreach ($foodArray as $food)  {
 echo $food['color'] . ' = ' $food['name'] ."<br />";
}
```

You can multiple properties for each food item as it is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: `$foodArray = ['green' => 'apple', 'yellow' => 'banana'];` what if you have multiple green fruits?

Answer (score 2):

Using this method you can add other properties

```
$foodArray = [
   [
     'name' => 'apple',
     'color' => 'green',
   ],
   [
     'name' => 'banana',
     'color' => 'yellow',
   ]
];

//loop
foreach($foodArray as $food) {
    echo $food['name'] . ' have color ' . $food['color'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store multiple properties using an array, next approach using multidimensional array may help:

```
<?php
$foodArray = array(
    "apple" => array(
        "color" => "green",
        "size" => "small"
    ), 
    "banana" => array(
        "color" => "yellow",
        "size" => "medium"
    )
);

foreach ($foodArray as $fruit => $properties)  {
    echo $fruit."<br />";
    foreach ($properties as $key => $value)  {
        echo $key.": ".$value."<br />";
    }   
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
apple
color: green
size: small

banana
color: yellow
size: medium
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
//keyed array
$foodArray = ['apple' => 'green', 'banana' => 'yellow'];
// loop through array as key/value prop
foreach($foodArray as $fruit => $color) {
    echo $fruit." - ".$color ." <br />";
}
```

Comment: you are wright, makes more sense to put it around :)

Answer (score 1):

Your one property array

```
 $foodArray = ["apple", "banana"];
```

new array to add keys in first array

```
$key_array = ["green", "yellow"];
```

now to create array with green->apple, yellow->banana

```
$output = array_combine($key_array, $foodArray);
```